# Selecting security questions and entering answers

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dialog that houses 6 security questions and 6 security question answers.

I want to pass the data the user selects and enters from the view to the controller to save the data in session.  Right now, the code works perfectly but it is a mess. I am passing 12 arguments to my controller action! I am validating the answers and passing the data to session on submit.

Need help on refactoring and simplification.

Here's my view code:

```
var RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit = function () {

    ValidationAttribute.BlankValue(true);
    var form = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    var d = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').serialize();
    SecurityQuestionsValid = true;

    var inputs = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').find('input[data-val]');
    $.each(inputs, function (index) {
        var input = inputs[index];
        if (!$(input).valid()) {
            SecurityQuestionsValid = false;
        }
    });

    var dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");
    var dd1Value = $(dropdowns[0]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var dd2Value = $(dropdowns[1]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var dd3Value = $(dropdowns[2]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var dd4Value = $(dropdowns[3]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var dd5Value = $(dropdowns[4]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var dd6Value = $(dropdowns[5]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();

    var answer1 = $('#idAnswer1').val();
    var answer2 = $('#idAnswer2').val();
    var answer3 = $('#idAnswer3').val();
    var answer4 = $('#idAnswer4').val();
    var answer5 = $('#idAnswer5').val();
    var answer6 = $('#idAnswer6').val();

    if (SecurityQuestionsValid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit'),
            type: 'Post',
            data: {AnswerOne: answer1, AnswerTwo: answer2, AnswerThree: answer3, AnswerFour: answer4, AnswerFive: answer5, AnswerSix: answer6, SecurityQuestionOne: dd1Value, SecurityQuestionTwo: dd2Value, SecurityQuestionThree: dd3Value, SecurityQuestionFour: dd4Value, SecurityQuestionFive: dd5Value, SecurityQuestionSix: dd6Value},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                PopUpSupport.ClosePopup("RequestSecurityQuestions");
            },
            error: AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail
        });
    }
    return SecurityQuestionsValid;
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(string AnswerOne, string AnswerTwo, string AnswerThree, string AnswerFour, string AnswerFive, string AnswerSix, string SecurityQuestionOne, string SecurityQuestionTwo, string SecurityQuestionThree, string SecurityQuestionFour, string SecurityQuestionFive, string SecurityQuestionSix)
    {
        SecurityQuestions securityQuestions = new SecurityQuestions();

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerOne))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA1 = AnswerOne;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerTwo))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA2 = AnswerTwo;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerThree))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA3 = AnswerThree; 
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerFour))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA4= AnswerFour;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerFive))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA5= AnswerFive;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerSix))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeA6 = AnswerSix;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionOne))
        { 
        securityQuestions.ChallengeQ1Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionOne);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionTwo)) 
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeQ2Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionTwo);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionThree))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeQ3Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionThree);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionFour))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeQ4Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionFour);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionFive))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeQ5Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionFive);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionSix))
        {
            securityQuestions.ChallengeQ6Id = Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionSix);
        }
        UserSession.AddValue(StateName.CreateOrEditAccount, "CurrentSecurityQuestions", securityQuestions); 
        JsonResult res = Json(new { Success = true, data = "", Message = "" });
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: I added the string.IsNullOrEmpty() to the solution.

Comment: You are not supposed to alter the code in your question are receiving advice. Also you appear to have reversed the conditions with your edit from "not equals null/empty" to "equals null.empty"

Comment: Oh oops! It's supposed to be '!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerOne)' isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names like `AnswerOne` are easier to work with if they that the form `answer1` instead. You can then loop over them by incrementing an integer.

For example where you have

```
var dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");
var dd1Value = $(dropdowns[0]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
var dd2Value = $(dropdowns[1]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();
var dd3Value = $(dropdowns[2]).data("kendoDropDownList").value();

var answer1 = $('#idAnswer1').val();
var answer2 = $('#idAnswer3').val();
var answer3 = $('#idAnswer4').val();
```

and then later

```
{AnswerOne:answer1,AnswerTwo:answer2,AnswerThree,answer3,SecurityQuestionOne:dd1Value,SecurityQuestionTwo:dd2Value,SecurityQuestionThree:dd3Value}
```

you could instead have

```
var data={}, dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");

for(var i=1; i<=6; i++){
     data['answer'+i]=$('#idAnswer'+i).val();
     data['question'+i]=$(dropdowns[i]).data("kendoDropDownList").value()
}
```

or

```
var data={};

$("input.customdropdownlist").each(function(dd,i){

     data['answer'+i]=$('#idAnswer'+i).val();
     data['question'+i]=$(dd).data("kendoDropDownList").value()
});
```

or one of the other many ways to iterate in JavaScript.

The same goes for your server-side code. Iterating through the data it receives to check it for blank fields will replace that long list of `if` statements with a short simple loop that will be much easier to read and maintain.

```
for(int i=1; i<=6; i++){
    string a=Request.QueryString["answer"+i];
    string q=Request.QueryString["question2+i];
}
```

Comment: ah this could actually work. I'll give a try. Thanks! :)

Comment: In which case, in my controller, I would pass in my viewmodel instead of all those strings?

Comment: I'm not much of an C# or ASP expert but this should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375372/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-querystring-name-value-pairs-into-a-collection

Comment: I'm getting data is undefined here: var data={} even when I start adding to data.

Comment: Actually, I used your first approach and I renamed the array and it's fine. The problem is all the values that are getting passed are null and 0. So something is wrong with what I'm passing. How do I pass my values from view to controller properly?

Comment: Have you changed the variable names in your c# code to match the properties of the `data` object in your JS code? Try using the example in the link I provided above to report back exactly what parameters are being passed.

Comment: I don't think that example helps. It doesn't make sense :s

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` report if you add it to your JS just before the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: Ah I think that's my issue, I forgot to 'stringify' the data array? I have a similar issue to this: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1931721-5842991647310258176

Comment: You want to use an object `{}` not an array `[]` for the variable data.

Comment: Yes I am using object and I keep getting null. I will try the console.log

Comment: Before the ajax, the data object is correct. It's on POST that I'm getting empty values. I must be passing it in incorrectly!! I'm not sure how to pass in my data to my controller without it being empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25218/discussion-between-bob-and-kala-j).

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- `AnswerOne`, `AnswerTwo`: parameters should be camelCase
- `AnswerOne != "" && AnswerOne != null`: what's wrong with [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)?
- `Int32.Parse(SecurityQuestionOne);`: if you need `int`s, why not define the parameters as such?
- What is `SecurityQuestions`? I'm asking because class names shouldn't be a plural.
- `RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit`: [DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

WRT the problem in general: I haven't done any ASP.NET MVC, but surely you must be able to send [a custom class/model of some sort](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation) instead of a dozen parameters? If you look at that link, you'll see this code about halfway down the page:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375949/648075).

Comment: SecurityQuestions is the viewmodel and how come not plural? I mean it's houses the SecurityQuestion(s) and not just a question. Someone told me I can't pass in an int using AJAX, only strings. Is that correct? What's a better name for an onclick event for submission instead of the underscore name I used? Thank you so much for your help! This is why I'm here, to learn :)

Comment: yes normally, I would send over the validated data as a model but I'm dealing with getting the selected value of dropdownlist when I just submitted my data as  $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').serialize();, it wasn't passing in the selected value correctly, it was displaying it as 0 for all the selected questions.